# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root" in minikube

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, minikube

I am writing an app using spring boot, postgres and minikube. But when I apply app and db files I got an error:

Error by db:

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
DETAIL:  Role "root" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256".

Error by app:

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but no password was provided.

I dont know why postgres is looking for user "root" although I set user "postgres". Also I set configuration like

kubectl exec -it pod-name -- sh
psql -h postgres -U postgres

But it doesnt help. Thanks for advance

postgres-credentials.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-credentials
data:
  postgres_user: cG9zdGdyZXM=
  postgres_password: MTIzNDU=
```

postgres-configmap.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  # Name your ConfigMap
  name: postgres-conf
data:
  host: postgres
  name: PaymentLab3
```

postgres-deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
# Kind for volume chain
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  # Name the persistent chain
  name: postgresdb-persistent-volume
  # Labels for identifying PV
  labels:
    type: local
    app: postgresdb
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    # PV Storage capacity
    storage: 8Gi
  # A db can write and read from volumes to multiple pods
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  # Specify the path to persistent the volumes
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/db"

---
apiVersion: v1
# Kind for service
kind: Service
metadata:
  # Name your service
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  # Choose how to expose your service
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    # The port number to expose the service
    - port: 5432
  # Pod to route service traffic
  selector:
    app: postgres

---
# Define a 'Persistent Voulume Claim'(PVC) for Postgress Storage, dynamically provisioned by cluster
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim # name of PVC essential for identifying the storage data
  labels:
    app: postgres
    tier: database
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce   #This specifies the mode of the claim that we are trying to create.
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi    #This will tell kubernetes about the amount of space we are trying to claim.

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
    tier: database

spec:
  selector: # mysql Pod Should contain same labels
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: # Must match 'Service' and 'Deployment' selectors
        app: postgres
        tier: database
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres
          envFrom:
            # Load the environment variables/PostgresSQL credentials
            - configMapRef:
                # This should be the ConfigMap name created ealier
                name: db-secret-credentials
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgres
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgres-persistance-storage
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-persistance-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

deployment.yml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: lab4-minikube
  labels:
    name: lab4-minikube
spec:
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30163
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: lab4-minikube
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lab4-minikube
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: lab4-minikube
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: lab4-minikube
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: lab4-minikube
          image: 12413/lab4-minikube:1.5
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:   # Setting Enviornmental Variables
            - name: DB_HOST   # Setting Database host address from configMap
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-conf  # name of configMap
                  key: host
            - name: DB_NAME  # Setting Database name from configMap
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-conf
                  key: name
            - name: POSTGRES_USER  # Setting Database username from Secret
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials # Secret Name
                  key: postgres_user
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD # Setting Database password from Secret
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: postgres_password
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:5432/${DB_NAME}
    username: {POSTGRES_USER}
    password: {POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    hikari:
      initialization-fail-timeout: 0
jpa:
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect
  generate-ddl: true
  show-sql: true
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: create
```

Comment: Neither the configmap `postgres-conf` nor the secret `postgres-credentials` exist.

Comment: @Botje I added these files correctly, but I had the same error. You can see changes in post